# EF Auto-increment a non primary column with a seed value

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Order table and it has OrderNumber column of type INT. Order table also has a Id column which is Primary key. I need to make OrderNumber column to autoincrement the values from a Seed value. Any help?

Thanks
Anjan

Answer (score 1):

You can assign auto-increment to any column, but I would not do that, because `OrderNumber` is definitely identity of your Order entity. You should use it as primary key:

```
[Key] // make it primary key and remove Id property
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
```

Adding auto-increment with fluent api looks like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
   .Property(o => o.OrderNumber)
   .HasDatabaseGenerationOption(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity);
```

If you want to create seed for `OrderNumber` then you should use custom database initializer and execute [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) query

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Orders', RESEED, YourSeedValue)
```

Comment: Order table already has Id(Guid) column as Primary. Is there any method not not make OrderNumber as Primary and make it auto-incremented?

Comment: @user3260063 do as specified above. But I still suggest to remove guid id

Comment: I'd also agree with not using a GUID as a primary key - if you ever need to go in and do anything by hand, it's a pain. You also lose some optimisation you can get by having the PK be sequential. About the only time to do it is if you're clustering and even then having different seeds on different servers can help. Also make sure you avoid the approach of `Order = MAX(Order) + 1` _in code_ as it falls apart when two operations are done at the same time (common race condition).

Comment: I understood your point. But, We are following Guid as Primary column type for all tables. So changing that will not be possible in this case. I made OrderNumber as Identity, it took of Identity from Id column and it is throwing error that Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table Orders when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.